# 404 error accessing local host in android mobile device but works on pc browser

Tags: android, tomcat, netbeans

I run a web project  locally within **Netbeans**. So the **tomcat server** starts up and it can be accessed normally by typing localhost:8080 into some browser. Everything fine so far. But what I need is to access it from outside, say from a android mobile (which I connected by **wifi hotspot**  -obviously resides in the same wireless network). So when he types the following :8080 I should reach the locally running webserver (within Netbeans). But that doesn't work!

Some more details

Windows 7 OS
NetBeans 8.03
Webserver :Tomcat server
When launching the Tomcat server from within Netbeans I can access it with: `http://localhost:8080`

I cannot access it however from my local PC(where the webserver is running within Netbeans) with: `http://192.168.0.5:8080` where the IP is my IP address in the network.

The output on browser shows the following error

> HTTP STATUS 404 - [location specified in URL] 
>     TYPE : status report
>     MESSAGE: [location specified in URL]
>     DESCRIPTION : the requested resource is not available

**I have all Firewalls disabled!**

Comment: Which address are you using on your mobile device? `localhost` always represents the device from which you are making the request. It corresponds to the `127.0.0.1` loopback address, thus it can never be used for external communication.

Comment: your url should look like www.127.0.0.1/index.php and not www.localhost.com/

Comment: i just referred 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device'

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your web server is set up to use virtual hosts to decide what to serve and has a different configuration for your networked ip  address and localhost. Check for "host" tags in your tomcat configuration files and make sure they all use the same appBase setting.

Comment: i have connected both by wifi hotspot on my android mobile. So obviously they both have same ip address. dO you think is that a error

Comment: can you please explain in detail